# logwatch-7.4.0 reports pop3 and imap sessions as "unmatched"?

Tags: 11.10, dovecot

Since upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10 (and therefore dovecot 1.x to 2.x) logwatch is reporting the end of every pop3 and imap session as "unmatched."  I've been searching for a solution and found that logwatch-7.4.0 has at least one patch specifically for dovecot-2.x that is related to the pop3/imap log entries.  Is there a place where we mere users of Ubuntu can check the schedule to see when a package might make it to the repositories and/or request/suggest particular packages (such as the latest logwatch)?

I could manually install the latest, but in the past I've found that once I go "manual" on a package, it is very difficult to get back on track with the repositories later.

FWIW, I did replace the script for the dovecot service with the newer version and the report cleans up quite nice.  I'm sure other dovecot/logwatch users would appreciate getting logwatch-7.4.0 as much as I would.

Answer (score 2):

According to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) the next release of ubuntu(12.04) will have 7.4.0 in the repositories. You can also search for any package there and it should show which ubuntu release has which version of the package your searching for.